# Anyway I create JMeter scripts from IIS logs?

Tags: jmeter

I have a server that's crashing and we're having difficulty recreating it. My next thought is to take the IIS logs and somehow recreate the traffic it experiences, like the exact traffic, in a test environment. Anyway tools out there before I go making my own?

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to have a format for your logs similar to Apache HTTP or Tomcat Access Logs, you could try to use Access Log Sampler:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.pdf
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Access_Log_Sampler

A better way is to find out from logs or from Google Analytics (if you use it) the navigation scenario of your visitor and record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder) and then variabilize data to be the most realistic.